# Difference between base.wim and boot.wim

Tags: iso-image, wim

I'm trying to build a recovery ISO so I can expand it to a different computer, however I have 2 `.wim` files: `base.wim` and `boot.wim`.

`base.wim` is 10 GB while `boot.wim` is only 146 MB.

I've tried creating an ISO with AIK off the 10 GB wim (renaming it to `boot.wim`) but when I load it on my other computer I get a `winload.exe` missing error.

So my question is: what is the difference between the two and what can I do to make my recovery disk work?

Answer (score 2):

A boot.wim file is the Windows Preinstallation Environment (WinPE).
A base.wim file is the main Windows image. (I believe 'base.wim' is what HP generally call their installation WIMs)

Using a WinPE boot CD/USB you can boot into the boot.wim file which will take you into WinPE, from there you can use 'imagex.exe' or 'dism.exe' to apply the base.wim to another disk/computer.

Walkthrough: Create a Custom Windows PE Image:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc709665(v=ws.10).aspx

Apply Images Using DISM: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh824910.aspx

Comment: isn't that what `setup.exe` normally does?