# Windows : 6 partitions, winRe, RecoveryBoot & RecoveryImage

Tags: windows, partition-recovery

My HDD (with windows 10) have the current partitions :

```
Partition 1    System             300 M   1024 K
Partition 2    Recovery           900 M    301 M
Partition 3    Primary            279 G   1329 M
Partition 4    Recovery           350 M    280 G
Partition 5    Primary            397 G    280 G
Partition 6    Recovery            20 G    678 G
```

I have found this [forum](http://forum.notebookreview.com/threads/asus-partitioning-scheme-5-partitions-can-anyone-explain-thoughts.696083/) explaining in a global way. I know that the `partition 1` is for the EFI boot. The `partition 3` is for the OS and `partition 5` is for my files.

I am interested in are the recovery partitions. The `partition 2` is for the recovery mode, and it's created by the windows installer. The `partition 6` is for an OS recovery image, to reset the computer. I explored inside those 3 partitions. And I have the following structure :

**Partition 2**

```
. 
+--Boot
+--EFI
(...)
+--Recovery
|  +--WindowsRe
|     +--boot.sdi
|     +--ReAgent.xml
|     +--Winre.wim
(...)
```

I skipped some folders/files in `partition 2`.

**Partition 4**

```
.
+--Recovery
   +--WindowsRe
   |  +--boot.sdi
   |  +--ReAgent.xml
   |  +--Winre.wim
   +--Logs
```

and nothing else.

**Partition 6**

```
.
+--Recovery
|  +--Logs
+--RecoveryBoot
|  +--AsDiskLayout.dat
|  +--AsPartition.dat
|  +--BOOT.WIM
+--RecoveryImage
   +--install.wim
```

and nothing else.

---

**My questions are:**

1. Why I have 2 windows RE ? Is the one in `partition 4` useful ?
   because in `partition 2` the already is one, even if there is more
   files in.
2. `install.vim` is the image, but [here](https://superuser.com/a/686419/756412) it's said that "boot.wim file is the Windows Preinstallation Environment (WinPE)" but [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc765966(v=ws.10).aspx) is said that RE is based on PE. So do I need this too ?
3. Should I clean up and re-created all the recoveries partitions ?

Comment: Is your PC a pre-build one? Or do you install Windows 10 manually with DVD/USB drive?

Comment: My PC is a pre-build one, but it's quite old now, I had window 8 at the beginning and it passed thought 8.1 to 10. And I'm quite "curious" so I had to reset the computer after several fails.

Comment: May be your PC manufacturer created those partition. You may remove the recovery partitions. NEVER remove EFI partition.